# caching view controllers that storyboard segues between

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have a storyboard with a tabbar viewcontroller that loads a navigation controller that loads multiple view controllers. When you go from one view controller to the next and return back to the first view controller, the data gets reloaded. I would like to cache view controllers to avoid reloading the data. I do not want to load the view controllers programmatically. Is there a way to enable caching using the storyboard code?

Comment: “When you go from one view controller to the next and return back to the first view controller” what does that mean? Do you mean just within the navigation controller push push push and then come back, still in the navigation controller?  If so, what does the tab bar controller have to do with all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to cache the data that the `UIViewController` holds,  not the `UIViewController` it self when you **dismiss/pop** a `UIViewController` you remove it from the hierarchy of the `UIWindow` and when you **present/push** it again its life cycle reset and triggers again causing you to re-fetch the data that is represented in the `UIViewController` therefore, caching the data and checking on it when you **present/push** the `UIViewController` is what you're looking for .

Getting into that, i recommend looking into some local database that you're comfortable with an example of that would be [Realm](https://realm.io/) .

So simply when you fetch the data you store it in `Realm` then when you **present/push** the `UIViewController` you do a checkup on those data if they are exists else fetch them again, you can also do a schedule to clear the cached data after some amount of time.